# Wordpress Admin is broken due to error, how can I download a wordpress site from FTP to local?

Tags: wordpress

As I understand it, the normal process for copying a live wordpress site to local is done through the Wordpress Admin panel, unfortunately this is broken and giving me an error.

How would a person download a wordpress site to local the hard way by copying the files over FTP?

I am not the site owner, and am being brought in as a favor to the site owner, the site has been live for years and suddenly broke (probably the plugins)

Comment: Install a fresh wordpress in your local and just download the plugin folder and theme folder, then uploads folders if any and download the db of live and import in your local

Comment: thats what i'd like to do, but I cant find any documentation on where all those folders are located, or where those DB records are held to duplicate. All documentation directs me to use the export wizard that I cant get to

Comment: You can download all files through the hosting portal you are using & then setup database & config file for local server. It may help.

Comment: which plugin have you been used to duplicate it?

Answer (score 0):

**Step1** if you have live website FTP or control panel then
open it and create a zip file from Cpanel of the live site WordPress directories . if you have FTP then connect the FTP and select all files and drag it to the right to left into the new folder on the left side

**Step 2** when files will move to your system then start your localhost control panel, into ht docs folder move directories of WordPress here which one you recently downloaded from FTP of control panel make sure if you download zip folder from control panel it should be extracted first.

**Step 3** open you PHPMyAdmin and then create a database the name whatever you would like to .Then into ht docs WordPress folder open wp-config.php files and change the name of the database , the username will be root and password will be blank.

**Step 4** now go to your live site control panel and open PHPMyAdmin, open the corresponding database you can find the database name from the live site wp-config.php file. Now export it to the folder on desktop or you can direct put it to the desktop.

**Step 5** extract your live site database and edit it with a text editor something like notpad++. now press ctr+f and then select find and replace tab.Into finding input paste your live site name something wpbeginner.com and into replacing tab paste the localhost directory which one hold the files of WordPress you recently moved something like localhost/yoursite.Hit the replace all tab.

**Step 6** Now create a zip file again of the database which one recently open in text editor, go to you PHPMyAdmin localhost and open the database which one you create for the local website. Click on the import tab and then import your live database which one you created the zip from the text editor.

**Step 7** on your localhost/yoursite/wp-admin enter the username and password of your live website login and it will open the wp-admin dashboard click to visit site , if it is reidrecting to the live site then goto your localhoset/phpmyadmin select the corresponding database and the select the table wp-option table and change the url from live to you localhost directory
That's it